# Burning Fedora 15 iso on DVD

Tags: fedora-15

I am burning Fedora 15 iso. It was downloaded from Fedora website as a folder with two files: checksum and iso image. Should i burn both files (checksum and iso) or only iso ? I want to boot from the DVD.

Comment: You need to use a program that will take the ISO and burn it's contents to the DVD.  You don't want to have a DVD with nothing more than the .iso file on it, it's not going to be bootable.  Any well-written burning software should do this for you automatically, and warn you if you try to burn the ISO as a file on a data DVD.

Answer (score 2):

First, [verify your download](https://fedoraproject.org/verify). Once you've done that, burn the ISO to the disc.

Answer (score 0):

We have taken the same trip this weekend. I have just upgraded from F11 to F15. Woot!

I burned my ISO on a Mac. I only downloaded the ISO once, but the first time I burned the DVD (using DiskUtility to mount the virtual volume and straight away burned this as a disk) I did not follow the instructions to perform the checksum test. Half way through the F15 install, it failed. The error blamed the disk. The second time, I performed the checksum and then burned the disk. This time it worked. So what's my answer? For me the checksum step was performed by DiskUtility, so I didn't follow the Linux instructions. But make no mistake, the checksum is necessary step. Good luck.